# nginx redirect from .htm to urls without

Tags: nginx, rewrite, 301-redirect

Hi a new website is launched.
The former website had urls like this:

http://example.com/something.htm

the new site hasn't and looks like this:

http://example.com/something

How can I tell nginx to do this redirect permanetly (301).

I have tried    `rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.htm permanent;` without success.

```
location ~*\.(htm)${
            rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.htm permanent;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite as following

```
rewrite ^(/.*)\.htm(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;
```

And for backward compatibility with your former website you can try this

```
index index.htm;
try_files $uri.htm $uri/ $uri =404;
```

Comment: Thx a lot Federico.
It surely has been a long night. In which block should these entries be made - location ?

Comment: pu it into the location /

Thank you a lot

Comment: I think it will work also into the server location, but it's possible to put it into the / location to have better control over the content !